# %Temporary matrix for evaluation in A* algorithm

Tags: matlab

This temporary matrix has written in Matlab, could anyone please give me some explaination?.

```
%Temporary matrix for evaluation
EE=E;

n_neighbour_high=1;

for i=1:x_size
    for j=1:y_size

        %Check neighbours
        k=i-1:i;
        l=j-1:j;

        %If neighbours within the grid
        if min(k)>0 && min(l)>0 && max(k)<=x_size && max(l)<=y_size

            %If among all the neighbours there enough high elemets, all the block is high
            if sum(sum(double(EE(l,k)>0)))>=n_neighbour_high               
                E(l,k)=elev;                
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

let's break it down:

```
for i=1:x_size
    for j=1:y_size
```

means you are looping over every element of your 2d-Matrix.

```
    %Check neighbours
    k=i-1:i;
    l=j-1:j;
```

Here you are defining new variables called `k`and `l`which are basically the number before `i` and `j` up to `i` and `j`.
assuming `i = 2` would make `k` a vector with the values `[1 2]`. If `i` would be `3` then k would be `[2 3]` and so on... always the number before `i or j` and the number `i or j`.

```
    %If neighbours within the grid
    if min(k)>0 && min(l)>0 && max(k)<=x_size && max(l)<=y_size
```

Here you are simply checking if the indices are valid (inside the range 1 and the 2d-array size) (Some of these checks are unnecessary by the way) 
This is necessary to avoid the problem for the case `i or j = 1` where the values in `k or l` would get `[0 1]`.

```
        %If among all the neighbours there enough high elemets, all the block is high
        if sum(sum(double(EE(l,k)>0)))>=n_neighbour_high               
            E(l,k)=elev;                
        end
```

Here you are taking a sub 2d-Matrix from EE (`EE(l,k)`) of size (2x2) and you are counting how many of those 4 elements are bigger then 0 and (`sum(sum(double(EE(l,k)>0)))`).

```
            E(l,k)=elev;
```

If the number of elements are bigger then your threshold ``` n_neighbour_high``you are saving the value of ```elev`at exactly those positions into the matrix`E`.

I think it would really help you to learn to use a debugger (click the line number in your matlab editor so that you get a small red dot) 
[have a look at this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)

Comment: I'm so grateful of your explanation my dear. After your permission, I'm a beginner for matlab and C++. This code has written by supervisor and asked me to code it in C++. Now, i'm trying to understand it vey well, then try to implement it in C++. What are your suggests to improve myself?. Second could you please explain the rest of this code?.                                                                                                         %2D grid generator

%Grid size
x_size=80;
y_size=80;

%Grid resolution
d_grid=1;

%Obstacle elevation
elev=3*h;

Comment: % %Random grid generation, discrete height in big blocks
% 
mean_h=0;
sigma=elev;
k_sigma=2;
E=random('Normal',mean_h,sigma,y_size,x_size);
%R = random('name',A,B,C) returns a random number from the three-parameter distribution family specified by 'name' and the distribution parameters A, B, and C.
sigma_obstacle=k_sigma*sigma;
E=double(E>sigma_obstacle)*elev;

Comment: %Check points outside grid
if x0<x_size && y0<y_size
    error_start=1;
else
    error_start=1;
end

if xend<=x_size && yend<=y_size
    error_end=1;
else
    error_end=1;
end

Comment: @Haitham, I'm happy that I could help. 
Have you tried to use the debugger and look at the variables at every step of your code? This helps understanding code significantly. 

It is really difficult to have a look at the code if everything is without formatting in the comments. Can you please edit your answer and add the missing parts of the code there. Have a look at how to properly format code (add 4 trailing whitespaces). 
And if my answer helped, consider marking it as useful or even accepting it.

Comment: Yeah, your answer hepled me a lot. Forgive me, I'm not good at programming and a new for stack overflow either. If you need, can I send it on your e-mail, after your permission?.

Comment: @Heitham, no problem, we all started small. I would suggest you should first get comfortable using Matlab and especially the debugger. Then get comfortable using stackoverflow, how to accept answers and mark them as useful (arrows at left) so that other people immediately see what helped you. It would be a good start to edit your question and add the new code snippets from the comments. Then everybody can help you again. It is not useful to write emails because your question might be of interest to other people... And finally also note that comments are not for extensive discussions ;-)